# Vectorizing 'for' loops

Tags: matlab, vectorization

This piece of code works as I want it to, but in the spirit of good MATLAB code, is there a way to vectorize this (previous is a k x 1 vector):

```
start = zeros(k,1);
for i = 2:length(previous)
    if (previous(i-1) == -1)
        start(previous(i))= start(previous(i))+1;
    end    
end
```

What, in general, is the intuitive way to go about vectorizing code in MATLAB?

Comment: I'm not sure that your code does what you want it to. The following input will give an error: `previous = [-1 -1 1]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this without `find`, for maximum performance:

```
I = [false; previous(1:end-1) == -1];
idx = previous(I);
start(idx) = start(idx) + 1;
```

This also avoids the risk that `previous(end) == -1`, which would cause an index out-of-range error in the alternative.

Note that this doesn't work the same as your original if `idx` contains duplicated indices.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `find` command in MATLAB, which returns the index (`i`) for which a vector is `TRUE`. So:

```
% precache indices i where previous(i-1) == 1
idx = find(previous==-1)+1;
start(previous(idx)) = start(previous(idx))+1;
```

The reason I precache `idx` is in case that `previous` is a big vector and doing the `find` takes a while. Otherwise you could just do

```
start( find(previous==-1)+1 ) = start( find(previous==-1) ) + 1;
```

Comment: This would be better with logical subscripting

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like:

```
prev_is_minus1 = [false; previous(1:end-1)==-1]
start = accumarray(previous(prev_is_minus1), 1, k)
```

I believe this has the same effect as the code loop you posted.