# Vectorizing nested for loops in matlab

Tags: matlab, vectorization

How do we vectorize this sort of code in matlab?

```
for i = 1:N
for k = 1:64
    if (pixels(i,k)==1)
     p(character(i),k)= p(character(i),k)+1;
    end
end    
end
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Vectorizing for loop in matlab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8462330/vectorizing-for-loop-in-matlab)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should be equivalent:

```
[i,j] = find(pixels(i,k) == 1);
if ~isempty(i)
    ind = sub2ind(size(p), character(i), j);
    %   or, equivalently:
    % ind = character(i) + (j-1) * size(p,1);
    p(ind) = p(ind) + 1;
end
```